# How to query category based product on homepage in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm learning woocommerce developing. I'm trying to query  specific categories Product on Homepage. But i can't query specific category product as same as product page. Anyone can show me the right way to query specific category product.

Comment: There should be a plugin in the wordpress repos that do that. Please provide more informations, theme you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
         // change category
        'product_cat' => 'some-category',
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'title',
    );


$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts()) { 
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        get_the_title();
    }
}
```